# Z-score to percentile in PHP

Tags: php, statistics

I need a [z-score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) to [percentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) calculator in PHP. Is there a simple formula suitable to PHP or an already written function. What should I use?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want?: [z-Scores(standard deviation and mean) in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434648/z-scoresstandard-deviation-and-mean-in-php)

Comment: @Truth This is inappropriate for M.SE - it's a PHP question, not a mathematics question.

Comment: @JoshuaLückers That question isn't helpful for this one. That's about how to calculate a z-score from a sample, whereas this is about how to compute percentiles from z-scores (i.e. how to implement the [Normal CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF)).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Sorry about that, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way is aboulang2002 at yahoo dot com's contribute on PHP manual:

```
<?
function erf($x)
{
    $pi = 3.1415927;
    $a = (8*($pi - 3))/(3*$pi*(4 - $pi));
    $x2 = $x * $x;

    $ax2 = $a * $x2;
    $num = (4/$pi) + $ax2;
    $denom = 1 + $ax2;

    $inner = (-$x2)*$num/$denom;
    $erf2 = 1 - exp($inner);

    return sqrt($erf2);
}

function cdf($n)
{
    if($n < 0)
    {
            return (1 - erf($n / sqrt(2)))/2;
    }
    else
    {
            return (1 + erf($n / sqrt(2)))/2;
    }
}

$zscore = MYZSCORE;
print 'Percentile: ' . cdf($zscore) * 100 . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the PI constant in PHP?

Comment: just a note that it is from the PHP manual stats_stat_percentile function. Link is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-stat-percentile.php

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what the function names `cdf` and `erf` represent?